# Do overseas convictions appear in your home country's records?

Tags: germany, canada, criminal-records

I am a Canadian living in a European country. I was convicted of a misdemeanor and now have a record in that country. Would this country have shared the conviction with Canada?

Comment: It will also depend n the final judgement. Anything up to 90 days fine/imprisonment won't turn up in any issued Führungszeugnis in Germany. *According to the Federal Central Register Act, fines **from** 90 daily rates (or imprisonment) are included in the certificate of good conduct [Führungszeugnis].*

Answer (score 2):

No. As a general rule, criminal records are jurisdiction-dependent.

Certain multi-jurisdiction countries or political unions may maintain a single database (e.g. Canadian and Swiss criminal records are maintained by the federal government, as the criminal law is federal responsibility there) or point of contact for criminal record checks (e.g. the United States or the [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Criminal_Records_Information_System)).

Countries usually do not share the complete copy of their criminal records database, but subject to bilateral agreements may allow access by a foreign government to help foreign criminal investigation or for other specific purposes (e.g. U.S. and Canada border officials can access the records of foreign nationals requesting admission).

---

Note that for certain administrative procedures (e.g. certain employments, immigration applications and security clearances), you are required to provide criminal records for all countries you have lived in (with variosu definitions of "living in", e.g. more than six months) in the past (or past x years).